# How to load next scene when pressed a button while playing in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

This what I tried,
I was watching Brackeys

```
public void PlayGame()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
};
```

Comment: So? What is the question? Are you sure your scene(s) are all added to the build settings?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your script probably doesn't work if you have 1 scene, or the current scene is at the end of the list in Build Settings.
Also you can use it this way:

```
//Add scenes in inspector
[SerializeField] private List<Scene> _sceneList;

public void LoadNextScene()
{
  int currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;

  if (currentScene < _sceneList.Count)
     SceneManager.LoadScene(_sceneList[currentScene + 1].buildIndex);
  else
     print("Its last scene");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SceneManager.LoadScene()` method to load the Scene by its name or index in Build Settings.

The `SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex` gives you the index number of the current scene and you can add an incremental value to navigate to the next scene.

To do that,

- Create a new script named SceneController and methods as follows,

  ```
   using System.Collections;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using UnityEngine;
   using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

   public class SceneController : MonoBehaviour
   {
      // Start is called before the first frame update
      void Start()
      {

      }

      // Update is called once per frame
      void Update()
      {

      }

      public void LoadMenuScene() {
          SceneManager.LoadScene("MenuScene");
      }

      public void NextScene() {
          SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
      }

      public void ReloadScene() {
         SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
      }
  }
  ```
- Add the script to the Canvas object
- Add the method to the button `OnClick` event in the inspector

[image]

**NB: You can also use name or index values to load the scene (like LoadMenuScene)**

For more: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html